# Cocos2D: Access objects CGRect from a loop

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

Experimenting with Cocos2D collection detection and have some questions. First, some background:

This is my method for adding a new item to my game, located in a different class than my game layer. This is located in my Item-class:

```
-(void) addItem:(NSString *) theFileName: (NSMutableArray *) theArray{

        CCSprite *item = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:theFileName
                                            rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50 )];

        //Positions


        int minX = 160;
        int maxX = 360; 
        int xRange = maxX - minX;
        int xCord = (arc4random() % xRange) + minX;


        item.position = ccp(xCord, -5);

    [self addChild:item];

    [theArray addObject:item];
```

Then I use this method in my game layer, using a reference to the Item-class called ItemManager:

```
[ItemManager addItem:@"box.png" :itemList];
```

If I want to detect collision between two sprites, in this case a box and something else, I need to be able to use the box rect created in the addItem-method.

```
for(CCSprite *newItem in itemList){
//(if box rectangle collides with my players or whatever 

}
```

So how can I acces the rectangle created all the way back in the original method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would suggest using the boundingBox property of CCSprite for collision detection:

Example:

```
for(CCSprite *newItem in itemList) 
{
    // if box rectangle collides with my players or whatever 
    if (CGRectContainsRect([newItem boundingBox], [player boundingBox])) 
        // do something
}
```

Comment: Okey, seems to work, thanks man! Do you know if it matters if the sprite actually have a rect around it? Does the boudingBox take the rectangle in count I mean?

Comment: you are welcome:) mm I don't quite understand your question. Can you try to rephrase it or give a specific example? To explain a little further, this boundingBox is basically really just an axis-aligned bounding rectangle around your sprite (even if you scale or rotate it). To visualize this bounding box better, go to ccConfig.h in your cocos2d folder and set #define CC_SPRITE_DEBUG_DRAW 1.

Comment: Ahh, what a great feature! (For debugging purposes that is). Well, my question actually got answered when the boudingBox got drawn out. Thanks again, appreciate it!